# How to call a custom function along with the event when a file is modified?

Tags: python, watchdog

I need help in being able to make a call to my_custom_function when a file is being modified. I also want to have the state of file like file_change, file_delete, etc available. I've used watchdog, which supports predefined functions as first parameters to schedule(). I should be able to make custom call and do some operations on it. My use case is to get the file content before file modifications and after file modifications, using watchdog.

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import os

def my_custom_function():
    print "---"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = os.path.abspath(".")
    my_event = my_custom_function()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(my_event, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: What is your question?  In what way does the above code not behave as you expect?

Comment: this code helps in observing file change event on a folder using schedule(). How should this be used in order to make a custom function call or is there any way to make such calls or not is my question. As simple as that...

Answer (score 3):

Hope the below code will answer your question.

```
import sys
import time
import watchdog
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
import time
from threading import Thread

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):

    def process(self, event):
        print "I am being processed"

    def on_modified(self, event):
        print "file modified " + event.src_path
        self.process(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        print "file created" + event.src_path
        self.process(event)

    def on_moved(self, event):
        print "file moved" + event.src_path
        self.process(event)

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        print "file deleted" + event.src_path
        self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]  
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path=args[0] if args else '.')
    print "Start"
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

For more information http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html

Comment: this is what I wanted.. thanks romil and siha. I wonder why people with good reputation are unable to understand things. This no place for blabbers.